# How to make an object on the screen rotates , in swift

Tags: swift, rotation, sprite-kit

I am creating an Iphone game in Xcode using swift , and there is a ball i want it to keep constantly rotating , i think i need to do it with the update method , but how could i do it , and if there another way with out using the update method please let me know

Comment: Are you using SpriteKit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an `SKAction` (take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/); you'll see `SKActions` have a variety of uses). For a rotation you could do:

```
// The angle is measured in radians and the duration is measured in seconds.
let rotateAction = SKAction.rotateByAngle(1, duration: 1)
```

To make the action run forever you can use another `SKAction`:

```
let repeatAction = SKAction.repeatActionForever(rotateAction)
```

Finally, you need to make your node (ball) run the action:

```
ball.runAction(repeatAction)
```

Take a look at the [`SKNode` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/runAction:) for other methods you can use to run an `SKAction`.

Also, I'm assuming you're new to Sprite Kit, so I'd recommend you take a look at [The Sprite Kit Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html).